# How to convert sync and async recursive function to iteration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, asynchronous, recursion

Looking for a specific implementation for both sync and async recursive functions that could be used as a starting point to turn future recursive functions into flat iteration.

Below are two examples of recursive functions: **Synchronous** and **Asynchronous**.

What I am looking for is an implementation of both using a **stack without recursion**.

For example, maybe it would work like this:

```
var output = syncStack(myRecursiveFunctionTurnedIterative, [])
```

Or if that's not possible, then just a reimplementation of the two functions below using a stack, and that should be a good enough start. E.g.

```
var stack = []

function circularReferences(object, references, stack) {
  var output = {}
  if (object.__circularid__) return true
  Object.defineProperty(object, '__circularid__', { value: id++ })
  for (var key in object) {
    var value = object[key]
    if (value && typeof value == 'object') {
      console.log(value)
      stack.push(???)
      circularReferences()
      stack.pop()
      if (is) output[key] = '[Circular]'
    } else {
      output[key] = value
    }
  }
}
```

The reason for this question is, I have tried over the years to learn how to do this, but have never found a system that is (a) easy to remember how to do, and (b) practical.

#### Synchronous

```js
var references = {}
var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: 10,
          f: 11,
          g: 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
object.a.b.c.d.x = object
object.a.b.c.d.y = object.a.b

var id = 1

var x = circularReferences(object, references)
console.log(x)

function circularReferences(object, references) {
  var output = {}
  if (object.__circularid__) return true
  Object.defineProperty(object, '__circularid__', { value: id++ })
  for (var key in object) {
    var value = object[key]
    if (value && typeof value == 'object') {
      console.log(value)
      var is = circularReferences(value, references)
      if (is) output[key] = '[Circular]'
    } else {
      output[key] = value
    }
  }
}
```

#### Asychronous

```js
var items = [
  async1a,
  async1b,
  async1c
  // ...
]

asynca(items, function(){
  console.log('done')
})

function asynca(items, callback) {
  var i = 0

  function next() {
    var item = items[i++]
    if (!item) return callback()

    item(next)
  }
}

function async1a(callback) {
  // Some stuff...
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (true) {
      var items = [
        async2a,
        // ...
      ]

      asynca(items, callback)
    } else {
      callback(null, true)
    }
  }, 200)
}

function async1b(callback) {
  // Some stuff...
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (true) {
      var items = [
        async2a,
        // ...
      ]

      asynca(items, callback)
    } else {
      callback(null, true)
    }
  }, 200)
}

function async1c(callback) {
  // Some stuff...
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (true) {
      var items = [
        async2a,
        // ...
      ]

      asynca(items, callback)
    } else {
      callback(null, true)
    }
  }, 200)
}

function async2a(callback) {
  return callback()
}
```

For example, that may start looking something like:

```
var items = [
  async1a,
  async1b,
  async1c
  // ...
]

asynca(items, function(){
  console.log('done')
}, [])

function asynca(items, callback, stack) {
  var i = 0

  function next() {
    var item = items[i++]
    if (!item) return callback()
    stack.push(item)
  }
}
```

But that's where I get lost. Not sure **how to pass around the stack** and **how the functions should be setup in general**.

Wondering how to in practice write those as non-recursive functions. I've seen [Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) but they are all very theoretical.

Comment: There ain't the one solution for all cases. Or the other way around: if you build one solution that covers all cases, then this solution is way too complicated for most of them. Why are you asking this question? What are you looking for?

Comment: I'm just looking for a design pattern for it. I haven't found one that makes sense.

Comment: @LancePollard one of the reasons you aren't going to be able to rewrite them in a truly general way is that you have traversal of an arbitrary depth, where each node has an arbitrary number of children.
You can get half-way there, but what will end up happening is you will end up nesting `while` loops inside of `while` loops (or `for` inside of `for`), where the number of loops matches the expected maximum depth.
You can get around some of that by hard-coding the depth numbers, but to automate that, you need recursion, anyway, and then you might as well finish the job while there.

Comment: @LancePollard and with asynchronous problems involving callbacks, that's just not going to work at all. There are ways of doing recursion without blowing the stack, or without completely blocking the main thread, even so far as to deferring to a separate thread, if the size of your problem warrants the cost incurred by serialization and starting up another process/worker. But without code-generation of some form, you're not going to be able to unroll to arbitrary depths to perform generic tasks, without recursion in some form.

Comment: @Norguard okay then maybe not a generic solution, just a specific solution to these two problems and I can go from there. Thank you for the clarification, that sounds complicated. I really would like to see how it changes the implementation of the async function, so I can learn how to apply it to custom async functions.

Comment: You might be interested in looking into the up and coming asyncitertaor interface: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration

Comment: `circularReferences` have lots of warts.. It has parameters that is **never used**, It makes an `output` object that is never used. It only `return` when it hits a match, but then if this is a sub object it will only touch the non returned object and end up returning `undefined` even though it has circular reference. Async version isn't really recursive since it rewinds the stack each time and since you rely on callbacks to do the next step you cannot rewrite this as a loop.

Comment: @Sylwester Async version is even more interesting than recursive (see my stack implementation) -- it re-calls not the same function but a function that was defined inside another function (`next`), storing local variables from specific calls to `asynca`, and is used as a callback all the way until the first `done` callback is achieved. If we do not pass the `next` callback parameter correctly to the stack, the chain of causality would never terminate. In the Synchronous version, I find it interesting to simulate returning `undefined` during the process and having "dangling" unused variables.

Comment: Looks like a while loop blocks the event loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824460/why-does-a-while-loop-block-the-node-event-loop. So the only way to handle async clearing the stack is with a timeout (I think).

Comment: @LancePollard I added an additional section about converting your particular example to tail-recursive to make for a straightforward stack implementation. Of course, this is a broad concept, more for thought than attempting to generalize it through code.

Comment: Here's my attempt to apply Ryan Hanekamp's idea: https://ideone.com/nJgDFf As we can see, the code is getting recursion-depth limit exceeded. Could Ryan or someone else please possibly fork my code or otherwise show an example of how we can use his idea to get past recursion-depth limits? Obviously, the stack implementation there works fine.

Comment: Ha! Please see here for another example of a non-tail-recursive conversion to stack, just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097634/how-to-calculate-this-sequence-iteratively/48098581#48098581

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for us to convert a procedure with a function that calls out to another function (whether or not it's the same function, aka 'recursive', makes no difference), we will need to separate it into the procedure that occurs before such a call and any procedures subsequent to the call. If there are no procedures after the out-call and the out-call is to the same function, we can describe it as "tail recursive," which can make the conversion to iterative much much simpler, simply pushing the call parameters to the stack ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992049/choosing-coins-with-least-or-no-change-given/34093666#34093666)). In fact, converting tail-recursion to an iterative stack process has helped me overcome browsers' recursion-depth limits in more than one real instance.

### Converting to tail-recursive

In order to convert a recursion to tail-recursive, we must consider how the information delivered from the recursive call is processed and whether we can transform this process to utilize parameters in the recursion itself. Since in your particular example, the only thing that happens with the out-call result is the setting of the local variable, `output`, and `output` is an object, which in JavaScript is passed by reference, we are in a position to make this transformation. So here's a simple refactor that will enable us to use a succinct stack (I skipped over the tail-recursive code to the stack implementation; left as an exercise for the reader):

```js
var references = {}
var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: 10,
          f: 11,
          g: 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
object.a.b.c.d.x = object
object.a.b.c.d.y = object.a.b

var id = 1

//var x = circularReferences(object, references)
//console.log(x)

//function circularReferences(object, references) {
// => add parameters, 'output' and 'key'
var stack = [[object, references, null, null]];

while (stack.length){
  [_object, _references, _callerOutput, _key] = stack.pop()

  var output = {}
  
  if (_object.__circularid__){
    _callerOutput[_key] = '[Circular]'
    
    // Log our example
    console.log('OUTPUT VALUE: ' + JSON.stringify(_callerOutput))
    
    // Exit
    continue;
  }
  
  Object.defineProperty(_object, '__circularid__', { value: id++ })
  
  for (var key in _object) {
    var value = _object[key]
    
    if (value && typeof value == 'object') {
      console.log(value)
      
      //var is = circularReferences(value, references)
      // if (is) output[key] = '[Circular]'
      stack.push([value, _references, output, key])
        
    } else {
      output[key] = value
    }
  }
}
```

### Generalizing the stack and ordering operations

Since it may not always be easy and straightforward to transform a recursion to tail-recursive, let's consider how we can use the stack to order operations iteratively in a way similar to the original recursion. We'll also generalize our stack a bit, which will help us with your second, "Asynchronous," example. Rather than only the call parameters, let's store both which function to call as well as the parameters. Something like:

```
(stack) [
  [function A, parameters for this call of A, additional refs for this call of A],
  [function B, parameters for this call of B, additional refs for this call of B]
]
```

As we know, a stack operates "last in, first out," which means if we have a function with operations subsequent to an out-call to another function, those subsequent operations will need to be pushed to the stack *before* the out-call so that the order of processing from the stack will be something like:

```
(stack) [first_call]
pop stack
  => first_call:
       process procedure before out_call
       push procedure after out_call
         => (stack) [procedure after out_call]
       push out_call
         => (stack) [procedure after out_call,
                     out_call]
pop stack
  => out_call
     (maybe followed by a whole other series of stack interactions)
pop stack
  => procedure after out_call (maybe use stored result)
```

(All of this is a bit of a hack to utilize the stack concept to order our operations. If you want to get real fancy (and even more complicated), code each *instruction* as a function and simulate an actual [call stack](https://www.google.com/search?q=call%20stack) with the ability to pause the next instruction in the main program as calls to other functions are pushed to it.)

Now let's apply this idea to your examples:

### Synchronous example

Not only do we have after-out-call procedures here, but we have an entire for-loop with such calls. (Please note that the console logs viewed directly in the snippet viewer are incomplete. Observe your browser's JS console for the complete logs.)

```js
var references = {};
var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: 10,
          f: 11,
          g: 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

object.a.b.c.d.x = object;
object.a.b.c.d.y = object.a.b;

var id = 1;


let iterativeProcess = {
  stack: [],
  currentResult: undefined,
  start: function(){
    // Garbage collector :)
    iterativeProcess.currentResult = undefined

    console.log('Starting stack process')
    
    // Used for debugging, to avoid an infinite loop
    let keep_going = 100;
    
    while (iterativeProcess.stack.length && keep_going--){
        let [func_name, func, params, refs] = iterativeProcess.stack.pop();

        console.log('\npopped: [' + func_name + ', ' + params + ', ' + JSON.stringify(refs) + ']');
        
        params.unshift(refs);
        
        func.apply(func, params);
    }
    
    return 'Stack process done\n\n';
  }
};


let circularReferences = {
  preOutCall: function(refs, _object, _references){
    var output = {};
    
    if (_object.__circularid__){
      console.log('preOutCall: _object has __circularid__ setting currentResult true')
      iterativeProcess.currentResult = true;
      
      // Exit
      return;
    }
    
    Object.defineProperty(_object, '__circularid__', { value: id++ })
    
    // Push post-out-call-procedure to stack
    console.log('Pushing to stack postOutCall ' + Object.keys(_object)[0])
    iterativeProcess.stack.push(['postOutCall', circularReferences.postOutCall, [], output]);
    
    // Call for-loop in reverse
    let keys = Object.keys(_object);

    for (let i=keys.length-1; i >=0; i--)
      circularReferences.subroutineA(output, _object, keys[i], _references);
  },
  
  subroutineA: function(refs, _object, key, _references){
    var value = _object[key];
      
    if (value && typeof value == 'object'){
      console.log('subroutineA: key: ' + key + '; value is an object: ' + value);
      
      console.log('Pushing to stack postSubroutineA ' + key)
      iterativeProcess.stack.push(['postSubroutineA', circularReferences.postSubroutineA, [key], refs]);
      
      // Push out-call to stack
      console.log('Pushing to stack preOutCall-' + key)
      iterativeProcess.stack.push(['preOutCall-' + key, circularReferences.preOutCall, [value, _references], refs]);
  
    } else {
      console.log('subroutineA: key: ' + key + '; value is not an object: ' + value);
      console.log('Pushing to stack subroutineA1 ' + key)
      iterativeProcess.stack.push(['subroutineA1', circularReferences.subroutineA1, [key, value], refs]);
    }
  },
  
  subroutineA1: function(refs, key, value){
    console.log('subroutineA1: setting key ' + key + ' to ' + value);
    
    refs[key] = value;
  },
  
  postSubroutineA: function(refs, key){
    let is = iterativeProcess.currentResult; //circularReferences(value, _references)
        
    if (is){
      refs[key] = '[Circular]';
      
      console.log('postSubroutineA: Object key: ' + key + ' is circular; output: ' + JSON.stringify(refs));
      
    } else {
      console.log('postSubroutineA: key: ' + key + '; currentResult: ' + iterativeProcess.currentResult + '; output: ' + JSON.stringify(refs));
    }
  },
  
  postOutCall: function(){
    // There is no return statement in the original function
    // so we'll set current result to undefined
    iterativeProcess.currentResult = undefined;
  }
};

// Convert the recursive call to iterative

//var x = circularReferences(object, references)
//console.log(x)
console.log('Pushing to stack')
iterativeProcess.stack.push(['preOutCall', circularReferences.preOutCall, [object, references]]);
console.log(iterativeProcess.start());
```

### Asychronous example

(I took the liberty to add a call to `next()` at the end of `asynca`, which I think you forgot.)

Here, in addition to multiple, interweaving function calls, we have the complication that calls are asynchronous, which basically means there will be more than one stack process. Since in this particular example stack-processes won't overlap in time, we'll just use one stack, called sequentially. (Please note that the console logs viewed directly in the snippet viewer are incomplete. Observe your browser's JS console for the complete logs.)

```js
let async = {
  asynca: function(refs, items, callback){
    let i = 0;
    
    function next(refs){
      console.log('next: i: ' + i);
      
      let item = items[i++];
      
      if (!item){
        console.log('Item undefined, pushing to stack: callback');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['callback', callback, [], refs]);
        
      } else {
        console.log('Item defined, pushing to stack: item');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['item', item, [next], refs]);
      }
    }
      
    console.log('asynca: pushing to stack: next');
    iterativeProcess.stack.push(['next', next, [], refs]);
  },

  async1a: function(refs, callback) {
    // Some stuff...
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (true) {
        var items = [
          async.async2a,
          // ...
        ]
  
        console.log('async1a: pushing to stack: asynca');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['asynca', async.asynca, [items, callback], refs]);
        
      } else {
        console.log('async1a: pushing to stack: callback');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['callback', callback, [null, true], refs]);
      }
      
      // Since there was a timeout, we have to restart the stack process to simulate
      // another thread
      iterativeProcess.start();
    }, 200)
  },

  async1b: function(refs, callback) {
    // Some stuff...
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (true) {
        var items = [
          async.async2a,
          // ...
        ]
  
        console.log('async1b: pushing to stack: asynca');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['asynca', async.asynca, [items, callback], refs]);
  
      } else {
        console.log('async1b: pushing to stack: callback');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['callback', callback, [null, true], refs])
      }
      
      // Since there was a timeout, we have to restart the stack process to simulate
      // another thread
      console.log(iterativeProcess.start());
    }, 200)
  },

  async1c: function(refs, callback) {
    // Some stuff...
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (true) {
        var items = [
          async.async2a,
          // ...
        ]
  
        console.log('async1c: pushing to stack: asynca');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['asynca', async.asynca, [items, callback], refs]);
        
      } else {
        console.log('async1c: pushing to stack: callback');
        iterativeProcess.stack.push(['callback', callback, [null, true], refs]);
      }
      
      // Since there was a timeout, we have to restart the stack process to simulate
      // another thread
      console.log(iterativeProcess.start());
    }, 200)
  },

  async2a: function(refs, callback) {
    console.log('async2a: pushing to stack: callback');
    iterativeProcess.stack.push(['callback', callback, [], refs]);
  }
}

let iterativeProcess = {
  stack: [],
  currentResult: undefined,
  start: function(){
    // Garbage collector :)
    iterativeProcess.currentResult = undefined

    console.log('Starting stack process')
    
    // Used for debugging, to avoid an infinite loop
    let keep_going = 100;
    
    while (iterativeProcess.stack.length && keep_going--){
        let [func_name, func, params, refs] = iterativeProcess.stack.pop();

        console.log('\npopped: [' + func_name + ', [' + params.map(x => typeof x)  + '], ' + JSON.stringify(refs) + ']');
        
        params.unshift(refs);
        
        func.apply(func, params);
    }
    
    return 'Stack process done\n\n';
  }
};

let _items = [
  async.async1a,
  async.async1b,
  async.async1c
  // ...
];

console.log('Pushing to stack: asynca');
iterativeProcess.stack.push(['asynca', async.asynca, [_items, function(){console.log('\ndone')}]]);
console.log(iterativeProcess.start());
```

### Call stack emulation

I'm not sure if I'll have time to get to this but here are some ideas for a general template. Separate functions that call other functions into relevant smaller functions to enable a pause in execution, perhaps code them as an object with an array of operations and keys to simulate local variables.

Then write a controller and interface that can distinguish a call to another function (similarly coded if it also has out-calls), push that "function"'s object (or stack-frame) onto the stack, remembering the place of the next instruction in line. There are many creative ways this can be accomplished with JavaScript, using object keys for the "return address" of the called function, for example, that the controller can be made aware of.

As others have noted here, each function with a call to another function presents its own challenge to convert it to an iterative sequence. But there may be many functions that could be amenable to such a scheme, and allow us to benefit from the added control of execution limits and sequencing.

Comment: Please see here for another example of a non-tail-recursive conversion to stack, just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097634/how-to-calculate-this-sequence-iteratively/48098581#48098581

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bad idea. I see benefit in this as purely an intellectual exercise, but you're forcing a very messy and complicated answer to a simple resource problem that could be solve by other means.

When a function in Javascript executes, it pushes a return address, function parameters, and local variables onto a stack. It's virtually impossible to get much savings on these with a naturally-recursive problem of indefinite depth by forcing it into a loop. A previous response (whose name I cannot type or even copy-paste well since it's in an RTL enconding) discussed tail recursion, and if you can fit the pattern you can get some slight savings of not pushing the return address onto the stack, but Javascript engines might be able to take care of that for you anyhow.

One difference and extra performance load compared to other languages, for example PHP, would be that Javascript also creates a closure for each invocation of the function. This could be trivial or substantial resource cost in very deep, very wide datasets, the type likely to actually cause a problem where one might think non-recursion would solve that problem. There is a means to invoke a function without a closure, however, by using the Function constructor. We shy away from these because eval-is-evil and they do take an extra step to compile, but once created, this might reduce any extra overhead from closures in deep recursion. The live compile performance hit should be more than compensated by reduced overhead in deep recursion calls.

Other performance drags can be creating an arguments object and execution context (this). We also now have arrow functions which will simply inherit the outer scope's instances. So the actual recursive portion should be an arrow function. If it needs a `this`, pass it by the outer `Function`'s closure, or pass it as a parameter.

Here's a general map:

```
const outerFunction=new Function(
    'arg1,arg2,arg3',
    `
        // Initialize and create items that simply must be transferred by closure
        ...
        const recursiveFunction=(param1,param2,param3)=>{
            ...
            const value=recursiveFunction(newParam1,newParam2,newParam3)
            ...
        }
        return recursiveFunction(firstParam1,firstParam2,firstParam3)
    `
)
```

Once into the general pattern, optimize the inner loop as much as possible. Don't build and recombine objects and arrays if the originals can be passed as references. Don't do any duckchecking or extraneous processing in the recursive portion. Javascript programmers aren't taught much about memory leaks, as the language has traditionally been short snippets that get wiped when the page is refreshed, so learn to spot instances where items no longer needed can't be garbage collected, and for that matter reduce items that need to be garbage collected if the problem is speed instead of memory. Remember that all primitives are immutable, and old values will be subject to being GC'd when assigned new values. Consider using Typed Arrays where sensible, to prevent this.

Even if this doesn't solve the OP's concerns, I hope this approach could be helpful to others who find this question on Google.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what "closures" in JavaScript actually are. I know that browsers limit recursion depth,  which is why sometimes an iterative stack can be beneficial (it actually was for me in more than one real instance). How would you suggest getting around this limit without converting recursive to iterative? Would the closure issue you described be related to that at all?

Comment: Here's my attempt to apply your idea: https://ideone.com/nJgDFf As you can see, the code is getting recursion-depth limit exceeded. Could you please possibly fork my code or otherwise show an example of how we can use your idea to get past recursion-depth limits?

Comment: No, I won't. You're constructing a special case example to support the general notion that creating a general pattern to flatten recursion is somehow not a waste of time. Your problem is one that is best solved by a loop, and not a "a naturally-recursive problem of indefinite depth" that I described. You got over 400 levels deep before your browser complained -- if your real-world problem is actually suffering from this limitation, then take the special case approach to put THAT algorithm into a flat loop.

Comment: Heh. All I asked for is for you to present an alternative to that will back your claim that converting recursion to iteration is "a bad idea," to use your words, which you have not provided. There are countless examples of recursions you'd be hard pressed to convert to a "loop" without a stack, one linked near the top of my answer. What's your alternative suggestion as to how to handle recursion-depth limits other than converting the recursion as the OP asked about?

Answer (score 1):

Let's just define a simple function, along with our parameters.

```
function syncLoop(iterations, process, exit){
    // Body of the function
}
```

Just to talk about the params real quick;

```
iterations = the number of iterations to carry out
process    = the code/function we're running for every iteration
exit       = an optional callback to carry out once the loop has completed
```

So we have our function shell, now we need to instantiate an index, and a boolean to keep track of if we're done looping or not.

```
function syncLoop(iterations, process, exit){
    var index = 0,
        done = false;
    // Body of function
}
```

Now we can keep track of where we are, and if we're finished or not (both important in loops!). The done boolean is going to be our way to check if we want to actually run again when called.

Right, this is where it gets slightly more complicated. We're going to create an object loop which is actually our loop object, and we're going to return it so we can control the loop from outside the function.

```
function syncLoop(iterations, process, exit){
    var index = 0,
        done = false;
    var loop = {
        // Loop structure
    };
    return loop;
}
```

I'll come back to this is a little while. Ok, so we have our loop. What's important to have in a loop? Well, we need a way to access the index, move on in the loop, and a way to kill the loop - so let's implement these methods.

```
function syncLoop(iterations, process, exit){
    var index = 0,
        done = false,
        shouldExit = false;
    var loop = {
        next:function(){
            if(done){
                if(shouldExit && exit){
                    return exit(); // Exit if we're done
                }
            }
            // If we're not finished
            if(index < iterations){
                index++; // Increment our index
                process(loop); // Run our process, pass in the loop
            // Otherwise we're done
            } else {
                done = true; // Make sure we say we're done
                if(exit) exit(); // Call the callback on exit
            }
        },
        iteration:function(){
            return index - 1; // Return the loop number we're on
        },
        break:function(end){
            done = true; // End the loop
            shouldExit = end; // Passing end as true means we still call the exit callback
        }
    };
    return loop;
}
```

Ok, to talk through this a little bit;

The `loop.next()` is our loop controller. Our process should call `loop.next()` when it wishes to complete an iteration and move to the next. Basically, all `loop.next()` does is call our desired process again, unless we're finished, in which case it calls the final callback.

The `loop.iteration()` function simply returns the index we're on. The first initialization means we'll always be one index ahead of the current iteration, so we return index - 1.

The `loop.break()` just tells the loop to finish on the current iteration. You can pass an optional value to tell the loop to end as normal and call the  `exit()` callback if desired. This is useful for loops which need to cleanup after themselves.

Right, we have a majority of the body here. So let's just kick it off, by calling `loop.next()` just before we return our loop.

```
function syncLoop(iterations, process, exit){
    var index = 0,
        done = false,
        shouldExit = false;
    var loop = {
        next:function(){
            if(done){
                if(shouldExit && exit){
                    return exit(); // Exit if we're done
                }
            }
            // If we're not finished
            if(index < iterations){
                index++; // Increment our index
                process(loop); // Run our process, pass in the loop
            // Otherwise we're done
            } else {
                done = true; // Make sure we say we're done
                if(exit) exit(); // Call the callback on exit
            }
        },
        iteration:function(){
            return index - 1; // Return the loop number we're on
        },
        break:function(end){
            done = true; // End the loop
            shouldExit = end; // Passing end as true means we still call the exit callback
        }
    };
    loop.next();
    return loop;
}
```

And we're done! All that matters now is implementing our loop and running it, so let's see an example;

```
syncLoop(5, function(loop){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var i = loop.iteration();
        console.log(i);
        loop.next();
    }, 5000);
}, function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

The above code simply prints out the current iteration we're with 5 seconds between each print, then logs done when complete. Go ahead and try it inside your browser console. Let's also check that our loop.break() works as expected.

```
var myLoop = syncLoop(5, function(loop){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var i = loop.iteration();
        console.log(i);
        loop.next();
    }, 5000);
}, function(){
    console.log('done');
});

setTimeout(myLoop.break, 10000);
```

In this scenario, we should see only the first two iterations printed before the loop is ended. Because we aren't passing a boolean value to  myLoop.break() it's not logging out done. We could change this by using the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myLoop.break(true);
}, 10000);
```

One important thing to note is that you can't kill a loop (cleanly) whilst in mid execution, it will wait until the current iteration is complete (which actually makes a lot of sense). It will just queue the break for the start of the next iteration, which is checked in loop.next().

Comment: This seems like a reasonable way to gain external control of an arbitrary iterative process. How does this answer the OP's question, namely, how to convert a function that calls itself to one that is amenable to such control?

Answer (score 1):

There's a general way to translate recursive function to use an explicit stack instead: Simulate the way a compiler might handle recursive calls. Save all local state on a stack, change the argument values to what would have been passed to the recursive call, and jump to the top of the function. Then where the function returns, rather than merely returning, check the stack. If non-empty, pop state and jump to the place where the recursive call would have returned. Since javascript doesn't allow jumps (`goto`), it's then necessary to do algebra on the code to transform them to loops.

Start with recursive code that will be a bit easier to deal with than your original. This is just a classical recursive DFS with "visited" marks for objects (graph nodes) we've already searched and "current" marks for objects on the path from topmost (root) object to the current one. We'll discover all cycles if for each object reference (graph edge), we check whether the destination is marked "current."

The current marks are deleted along the way. The visited marks remain after the graph has been searched.

```js
function get_back_refs(obj, back_refs) {
  if (obj && typeof obj == 'object' && !('__visited__' in obj)) {
    mark(obj, '__visited__')
    mark(obj, '__current__')
    var iter = getKeyIterator(obj)
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      var key = iter.next()
      if ('__current__' in obj[key]) {
        back_refs.push([obj, obj[key]])
      } else {
        get_back_refs(obj[key], back_refs)
      }
    }
    unmark(obj, '__current__')
  }
}

var object = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: 10,
          f: 11,
          g: 12
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
object.a.b.c.d.x = object
object.a.b.c.d.y = object.a.b

var id = 0

function mark(obj, name) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, name, { value: ++id, configurable: true })
}

function unmark(obj, name) {
  delete obj[name]
}

function getKeyIterator(obj) {
  return {
    obj: obj,
    keys: Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] && typeof obj[k] == 'object'),
    i: 0,
    hasNext: function() { return this.i < this.keys.length },
    next: function() { return this.keys[this.i++] }
  }
}

var back_refs = []
get_back_refs(object, back_refs)
for (var i = 0; i < back_refs.length; ++i) {
  var pair = back_refs[i]
  console.log(pair[0].__visited__ + ', ' + pair[1].__visited__)
}
```

Note that I think this fixes bugs in your code. Since the hierarchy is a general directed graph, you want to avoid searching objects twice. Skipping this can easily lead to run time exponential in the graph size. Yet, shared structure in the graph doesn't necessarily mean there's a cycle. The graph could be a DAG - directed and acyclic.

In this case, the local state is contained nicely in the iterator, so that's all we need on the stack:

```
function get_back_refs2(obj, back_refs) {
  var stk = []
  var iter = null
 start:
  if (obj && typeof obj == 'object' && !('__visited__' in obj)) {
    mark(obj, '__visited__')
    mark(obj, '__current__')
    iter = getKeyIterator(obj)
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      var key = iter.next()
      if ('__current__' in obj[key]) {
        back_refs.push([obj, obj[key]])
      } else {
        stk.push(iter) // Save state on stack.
        obj = obj[key] // Update parameter value.
        goto start     // Eliminated recursive call.          
       rtn:            // Where call would have returned.
      }
    }
    unmark(obj, '__current__')
  }
  if (stk.length == 0) return
  iter = stk.pop()  // Restore iterator from stack.
  obj = iter.obj    // Restore parameter value.
  goto rtn
}
```

Now to eliminate the `goto`s. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039639/what-is-the-algorithm-to-traverse-a-non-binary-tree-without-recursion-using-sta/48039964#48039964) describes a very similar transformation for searching a tree rather than a general graph, so I won't belabor it here. We end up with this intermediate result:

```
function get_back_refs2(obj, back_refs) {
  var stk = []
  var iter = null
  for (;;) {
    if (obj && typeof obj == 'object' && !('__visited__' in obj)) {
      mark(obj, '__visited__')
      mark(obj, '__current__')
      iter = getKeyIterator(obj)
      var key = null
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        key = iter.next()
        if ('__current__' in obj[key]) back_refs.push([obj, obj[key]])
        else break
      }
      if (key) {
        stk.push(iter)
        obj = obj[key]
        continue           
      }
      unmark(obj, '__current__')
    }
    for(;;) {
      if (stk.length == 0) return
      iter = stk.pop()
      obj = iter.obj
      var key = null
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        key = iter.next()
        if ('__current__' in obj[key]) back_refs.push([obj, obj[key]])
        else break
      }
      if (key) {
        stk.push(iter)
        obj = obj[key]
        break
      }           
      unmark(obj, '__current__')
    }
  }
}
```

Replacing `goto`s with the code they cause to execute results in repetition. But we can DRY that up with a shared local function:

```
function get_back_refs2(obj, back_refs) {
  var stk = []
  var iter = null
  var descend_to_next_child = function() {
    var key = null
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      key = iter.next()
      if ('__current__' in obj[key]) back_refs.push([obj, obj[key]])
      else break
    }
    if (key) {
      stk.push(iter)
      obj = obj[key]
      return true           
    }
    unmark(obj, '__current__')
    return false
  }
  for (;;) {
    while (obj && typeof obj == 'object' && !('__visited__' in obj)) {
      mark(obj, '__visited__')
      mark(obj, '__current__')
      iter = getKeyIterator(obj)
      if (!descend_to_next_child()) break
    }
    for(;;) {
      if (stk.length == 0) return
      iter = stk.pop()
      obj = iter.obj
      if (descend_to_next_child()) break
    }
  }
}
```

Unless I made an algebra mistake, which is certainly possible, this is a drop-in replacement for the original recursive version.

Though the method doesn't involve reasoning beyond the code algebra, now that we're done it's pretty clear that the first loop descends into the graph, always to the first child it finds that isn't a back-reference, pushing iterators onto the stack as it goes.  The second loop pops the stack looking for an iterator with work left to do: at least one child to search. When it finds one, it returns control to the first loop. This is exactly what the recursive version does, expressed in a different manner.

It would be fun to build a tool to do these transformations automatically.