# Python: how can this code be made to run faster

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, processing-efficiency

I am new to Python and I am slowly learning via Codewars. I know this is potentially against the rules but I have an efficiency question.

You are given a list of integers

ls = [100, 76, 56, 44, 89, 73, 68, 56, 64, 123, 2333, 144, 50, 132, 123, 34, 89]

You must write a function choose_best_sum(t, k, ls)

such that you find a combination of k integers from ls such that the sum of those k intergers is as close to or equal to t.

My final solution passes the tests but on the more detailed testing fails perhaps because of efficiency. I am trying to understand efficiency more. Here is my code

```
import itertools

def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    if sum(sorted(ls)[:k]) > t or len(ls) < k:
       return None
    else:
       combos = itertools.permutations(ls, k)
       return max([[sum(i)] for i in set(combos) if sum(i) <= t])[0]
```

Could someone highlight where the bottleneck is here (I assume on the permutations call) and how this function could be made faster?

EDIT:

The above solution profiled gave

1806730 function calls in 0.458 seconds

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.457    0.457 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.457    0.457 exercises.py:14(choose_best_sum)
742561    0.174    0.000    0.305    0.000 exercises.py:19(<genexpr>)
321601    0.121    0.000    0.425    0.000 exercises.py:20(<genexpr>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.458    0.458 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
    1    0.032    0.032    0.457    0.457 {built-in method builtins.max}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
742561    0.131    0.000    0.131    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

using the assistance I got my final solution was:

```
def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
   ls = [i for i in ls if i < t and i < (t - sum(sorted(ls)[:k-1]))]
   if sum(sorted(ls)[:k]) > t or len(ls) < k:
      return None
   else:
      return max(s for s in (sum(i) for i in itertools.combinations(ls, k)) if s <= t)
```

Ordered by: standard name

7090 function calls in 0.002 seconds

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 <string>:1(<module>)
 2681    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 exercises.py:10(<genexpr>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 exercises.py:5(choose_best_sum)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 exercises.py:6(<listcomp>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 {built-in method builtins.max}
   17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
 4385    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Check out `cProfile` to figure out exactly which line is slow.

Comment: Looks like https://www.codewars.com/kata/55e7280b40e1c4a06d0000aa

Comment: The bottleneck is the algorithm that you're using, list all the permutations is slow when you have a large list. Try to use two pointers (one at the beginning and one at the end) on sorted list, which has a time complexity of O(nlogn)

Comment: @GhostRider Yes it is codewars... except I linked to the *actual problem under discussion* rather than hand-waving at the site.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell Apologies - thank you

Comment: [Sum-subset with a fixed subset size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916539/sum-subset-with-a-fixed-subset-size). [Given a target sum and a set of integers, find the closest subset of numbers that add to that target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572043/given-a-target-sum-and-a-set-of-integers-find-the-closest-subset-of-numbers-tha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of obvious flaws in the expression

```
max([[sum(i)] for i in set(combos) if sum(i) <= t])[0]
```

1. You are running `sum(i)` twice for no good reason;
2. You are packing the result into a list (`[sum(i)]`) and then unpacking it (`[0]`)
3. You are converting `combos` to a set for no reason

Try replacing it with

```
sums = [sum(c) for c in combos]
return max(s for s in sums if s <= t)
```

**Edit:** ok, a few ideas on a better algorithm:

D'oh! First, use `itertools.combinations` instead of `itertools.permutations`. You are just taking the sum; the order of items makes no difference. If you are running on ie k = 4, `combinations` will return 4! == 24 times fewer entries than `permutations` on the same input data.

Second, we want to discard as many items as possible from `ls` at the very start. Obviously we can throw out any value > t; but we can get a tighter bound than that. If we add the (k - 1) smallest values, the largest allowable value must be <= t - (k-1)_sum.

(If we were looking for an exact sum, we could run this trick in reverse - adding the (k - 1) largest values would give us a minimum allowable value - and we could repeatedly apply those two rules to discard more possibilities. That does not apply here though.)

Third, we could look at all combinations of (k - 1) values, then use `bisect.bisect_left` to jump directly to the best possible k'th value. There's a bit of a complication, because you have to double-check that the k'th value has not already been selected as one of the (k - 1) values - you can't do that directly using the built-in `itertools.combinations` function, but you could use a modified copy of the [itertools.combinations code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) (ie test that `bisect_left` returns an index higher than the last one currently in use).

Together these should speed up your code by a factor of `len(ls) * k * k!`... Good luck!

**Edit 2:**

Let this be a lesson in the dangers of over-optimization :-)

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    """
    Find the highest sum of `k` values from `ls` such that sum <= `t`
    """
    # enough values passed?
    n = len(ls)
    if n < k:
        return None

    # remove unusable values from consideration
    ls = sorted(ls)
    max_valid_value = t - sum(ls[:k - 1])
    first_invalid_index = bisect_right(ls, max_valid_value)
    if first_invalid_index < n:
        ls = ls[:first_invalid_index]
        # enough valid values remaining?
        n = first_invalid_index   # == len(ls)
        if n < k:
            return None

    # can we still exceed t?
    highest_sum = sum(ls[-k:])
    if highest_sum <= t:
        return highest_sum

    # we have reduced the problem as much as possible
    #   and have not found a trivial solution;
    # we will now brute-force search combinations of (k - 1) values
    #   and binary-search for the best kth value
    best_found = 0
    # n = len(ls)      # already set above
    r = k - 1
    # itertools.combinations code copied from
    #   https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations
    indices = list(range(r))
    # Inserted code - evaluate instead of yielding combo
    prefix_sum = sum(ls[i] for i in indices)          #
    kth_index = bisect_right(ls, t - prefix_sum) - 1  # location of largest possible kth value
    if kth_index > indices[-1]:                       # valid with rest of combination?
        total = prefix_sum + ls[kth_index]            #
        if total > best_found:                        #
            if total == t:                            #
                return t                              #
            else:                                     #
                best_found = total                    #
    x = n - r - 1    # set back by one to leave room for the kth item
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + x:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        # Inserted code - evaluate instead of yielding combo
        prefix_sum = sum(ls[i] for i in indices)          #
        kth_index = bisect_right(ls, t - prefix_sum) - 1  # location of largest possible kth value
        if kth_index > indices[-1]:                       # valid with rest of combination?
            total = prefix_sum + ls[kth_index]            #
            if total > best_found:                        #
                if total == t:                            #
                    return t                              #
                else:                                     #
                    best_found = total                    #
        else:
            # short-circuit! skip ahead to next level of combinations
            indices[r - 1] = n - 2

    # highest sum found is < t
    return best_found
```

Comment: This is a great help. I can clearly see the excessive calls I have made based on your solution.

Comment: Although the tips in the answer are correct I'm pretty sure the detailed tests mentioned above will still fail. @GhostRider try to come up with a more efficient algorithm instead of trying every possible k-length permutation.

Comment: Yes, the detailed tests do still fail. I will still mark it as correct as it has highlighted many flaws in my code that are easily corrected and possibly useful. I suspect there is an elegant mathematical approach to that part of the code. I will keep working on it. Thanks

Comment: @GhostRider: added a few more ideas. Have fun :-)

Comment: Brilliant. Just changing to combinations made a huge difference. I'm going to post the cProfile results for each modification and final result when I've got it all sorted.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell Thanks a lot - learned much from this including the usefulness of profiling.